# Ruby, Watir, and how to fill out text fields inside of a Shadow DOM? (Safari)

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, shadow-dom

EDIT: PARTIAL SOLUTION FOUND: I was using Safari. Running the task through Chrome made turned what was in the Shadow DOM into the Light Dom so that I can now access it!

I am attempting to automate a browser task and automate some form filling with Watir, but I am having the hardest time trying to fill out text boxes in Shadow DOMs.

Image of the text field:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1KAk.png

This is the corresponding HTML for the Postal Code text field:

```
<input class="textbook" id="Fm2_Ctrol19_TextBox" name="Fm2_Ctrol19_TextBox" 
onchange="SearchJs.setBackgroundColor(this, SearchJs.checkTextBox_;" 
onkeypress="return 
SearchJS.onTextBoxKeyPress(event, this);" 
onkeyup="SearchJs.setBackgroundColor(this,SearchJs.checkTextBox);" 
onpaste="return SearchJs.onTextBoxPaste(event, this);" style="width:100px;
background=color: #ffffff;"
title="The zip code in which the property is located." type="text"> =$0

Shadow Content (User Agent) # The text field is in here, I imagine.

</input>
```

I am not familiar enough with javascript and Shadow DOM to know if the articles I have googled are relevant.

I have tried using plain' Watir in the past, but it comes out `Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException (timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::TextField: located: false; {:id=>"Fm2_Ctrol19_TextBox", :tag_name=>"input"}> to be located)` after a 30 second time out.

```
 b.text_field(id: 'Fm2_Ctrol19_TextBox').set 'POSTAL CODE HERE' # What I've tried
```

Does anyone have any information that could help me fill out that box?

Comment: Does that properly trigger the `onchange` handler?

Comment: @tadman Yes. It changes the background color from white to blue when text is inserted into the box.

Comment: Maybe fire the `onpaste` handler as well to be sure? It's worth noting that JavaScript seems to have syntax errors as well. `checkTextBox_;` vs. `checkTextBox);`

Comment: What is the error message you have gotten? Or what happened when you automated ?

Comment: And where did you get the nil? What returns? Give the clue as to what kind of error you are getting.

Comment: @tadman It isn't running. Even something as simple as `b.input(id: 'Fm2_Ctrol19_TextBox').exists?` or `b.text_field(id: 'Fm2_Ctrol19_TextBox').exists?`  is coming back `false`. 

@Rajagopalan I'll rephrase. It isn't coming back `nil`. After trying to locate the text field in IRB through the terminal one more time, I am getting `Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException (timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::TextField: located: false; {:id=>"Fm2_Ctrol19_TextBox", :tag_name=>"input"}> to be located)`.

It can't even find it.

Comment: That's the error message you should have included in your question. Can you once again confirm me whether it throws this error after waiting 30 seconds or throws this immediately?

Comment: @Rajagopalan This is after the 30 second time out.

Comment: No, let me make myself clear. I am not asking you to read the error and tell me, I am actually asking you to observe and tell me whether it really wait for 30 seconds and throws the error or it immediately throws the error.

Comment: @Rajagopalan It really waits for 30 seconds and then puts the error.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I found a partial solution. I switched form Safari to Chrome. I was not able to access the Shadow DOM, but running the task through Chrome gives me access to what was in the Shadow DOM in Safari because it appears in the Light DOM in Chrome.

Comment: Okay. Always use Chrome for automation and that's the best one as of now .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PARTIAL SOLUTION FOUND: I was using Safari. Running the task through Chrome made turned what was in the Shadow DOM into the Light Dom so that I can now access the data!